# Get User/Password textboxes when in Windows Welcome/Login screen

Tags: windows, login

When at the Windows "Login Screen"
(i.e. Windows showing users icons for login)

Is there any Keyboard shortcut (old Ctrl+Alt+Del)
or any other method to jump to the Windows "Logon Screen"
with textboxes asking for User and Password?

Comment: Yes : Ctrl+Alt+Del.

Comment: Yep... that was the first thing I've tryed...      :|                          but Ctrl+Alt+Del not working in windows 10 :(

Comment: You are right - this is disabled. Run *User Accounts > Advanced*; is the option you are looking for "Users must enter a username and password to use this computer"?

Comment: I want to use the default login dialog... so that is no solution too...

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have the other user accounts on the left-bottom side of the login screen?

Comment: I have the users at left-botton-screen... but I dont want the user list to be shown... just the old plain-login-screen,,, with a user and password textboxes.... ;-)